# python multiple if else condition

Tags: python

I have 2 conditions , when these are met i want it to mutiply with a number .
But my code is not giving desired result

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv(r'c\documents\afile.csv')

def f2(ro2):
    if row['country']== 'england' and row['age']=='':
       val = row[ecovalue]*0.8
    else:
       val = row[ecovalue]
    return val

def1['total ecovalue']=df1.apply(f2,axis=1)
df1.to_csv(r'c\documents\finalfile.csv',index=False,header=True)
```

so 2 conditions i.e country is england and all blank values of column age and if this 2 conditions are met then multiply with 0.8.

But I'm getting blanks cells in excel

Comment: Where is `ecovalue` variable defined? (or is it supposed to be the string `'ecovalue'`?)

Comment: Can you show the exact content of the CSV row you try to extract?

Comment: I think, `ro2` is a typo of `row`.

Comment: ecovalue is a numeric column